# How do I solve this Integral using an infinite series

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I'm supposed to use an infinite series to solve 
$$\int\frac{e^{2x}}{x}dx$$

How do I solve this? I know the answer already, I don't even have to use infinite series to solve this, however it was specifically instructed to have it solved by using infinite series.

Comment: Write down the series for $e^{2x}$, divide term by term by $x$, and integrate term by term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the power series for $e^{x}$ is
$$e^x = 1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dotsb + \frac{x^k}{k!}+\dotsb$$
Use this to get the series for $\frac{e^{2x}}{x}$ and then integrate term by term.